# JNDI lookups in OSGi in the bridged mode

Tags: java, osgi, jndi

## Background

I am embedding an OSGi runtime based on [Apache Felix in the bridged mode](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html#using-the-servlet-bridge) in a Tomcat6 container. There are a bunch of JDBC connections specified in the conf/server.xml file in Tomcat6.

```
<Resource name="foo/bar" ... />
```

## Question

The standard JNDI lookup doesn't seem to work from bundles deployed to the OSGi container.

```
ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/foo/bar");
```

Is there anything special that needs to be done for the OSGi runtime to be able to lookup resources registered in the parent Tomcat6 container?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your environment, is the ctx.lookup made inside a bundle activator or in an aries blueprint application? Due to forked threads, in our environment i was only able to fetch jndi-ressources inside of threads which have been started the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Martin's comment got me thinking about multiple threads part. I got this to work by:

1. Ensuring that `ctx.lookup(...)` is invoked in the `BundleActivator`. This is because, in the bridged mode, the `ClassLoader` of the thread running the `Activator` code can look up all Classes and Resources that are defined in the parent WAR file.
2. Ensuring that the parent WAR's `META-INF/context.xml` exposes the JNDI resource via `<ResourceLink global="foo/bar" name="foo/bar" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>`